# Rendering just html with Rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, rabl

I'm trying to figure out how to render **just** html with Rabl. I have an html partial without  an object, so far all I can see are examples of partials with objects. If I try it without the object it just (obviously) throws an error.

The closest I got was:

```
node(:content) do
    partial("api/v1/api/partials/tips")
end
```

[Here is the documentation for Rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl).

**UPDATE**

I ended up just going with this below. Obvious right? For some reason when I tried it the first time it didn't work. So for sending only HTML in API responses, this works well.

```
  def tips
    render partial: "api/v1/api/partials/tips"
  end
```

Comment: "system for generating JSON, XML, MessagePack, PList and BSON." - it doesn't say a thing about generating HTML. Why not use regular ERB?

Comment: The partial is erb. I need to send html to an iOS application, I'm open to better ideas :). Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3):

in a rabl view, for example `show.v1.rabl` you're able to render a view partial with the following (`rails 4.1.2`):

```
object @your_object

code :html do
  context_scope.controller.render_to_string(

     # from app/views/
    partial: 'path/to/show.html.erb',

     # locals (if needed)
    locals: { 
      your_object: @your_object
    }

  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by rendering an ERB template inside the Rabl node:

```
object @user

node(:html_content) do |user|
  @user = user
  template = Rails.root.to_s + '/app/views/api/users/show.html.erb'
  ERB.new(File.read(template)).result(self.binding)
end
```